# Retying shoes in order

Tags: halacha, shoes

In [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 2:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.2.4?lang=bi) it says:

> ואח"כ ינעול של שמאל ויקשרנו ויחזור ויקשור של ימין
> Then after that put on the left one and fasten it, and return and fasten the right one.

First you should tie the left shoe, and after that, tie the right one.

Does this also apply when retying your shoes, or is it only the first time you put them on (i.e. if both of my shoes untie at the same time, would I have to tie the left one first)?

Would it make a difference if I purposely untied my shoes in order to retie them?

---

<sub>adapted from [my question here](https://judaism.codidact.com/questions/276683)</sub>